# laravel socialite 3.0 getting error during Google+ login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

laravel

Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Project
>   892227784590 is not found (truncated...)

Comment: go to google console and enable API, you also need an API key

Comment: Thanks bro....its working for me. Write answer i will accept it or i have to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've created an application in [Google's console](https://console.developers.google.com) and also have your client id and client secret from google. Also make sure you've configured google option in your `config/services.php`.